# Thunderbird: Compose Message and set font-size for all (pasted) text

Tags: thunderbird, fonts

I am sure I am not the only one with this problem: When you write an email in Thunderbird v24.4 and you paste text copied from a website, the different formatting will appear as well. Thus there are different font-sizes in the email.

Problem with TB, there is no dropdown to set the font-size for the entire text! I have searched for addons, no luck.

On [mozillazine.org](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Default_HTML_font_for_new_messages_%28Thunderbird%29) I read: "Thunderbird does not provide a user interface for setting the default font and font size for the entire message." There they suggest to use the menu to >Insert >HTML and then add the line: `<style type="text/css"> body {font-size: 12pt;} </style>`

Well, that is not userfriendly at all, plus I don't want to spend 30 seconds on each email to get the same font-size for the entire text.

I hope I missed one addon in Thunderbird that can do it. Or somebody knows a trick how to achieve the same font-size?

Would be glad if you can help me out (and million other TB users with the same issue).

Thanks,
Kai

Comment: Oh... jus after finishing this post, I realized that the first drop down labeld with `Body Text` is about HTML elements. I highlighted the text and changed the dropdown to `Paragraph`. Obviously that is setting the same font-size! Can somebody confirm this?

Comment: I tried this on another computer later on, there using the "paragraph" dropdown did not set the same font-size. So the question is still open.

Comment: right click and paste as unformatted text? or ctrl-shift-v

Answer (score 0):

I am also not too happy with how Thunderbird does formatting. However, in order to solve/avoid your problem instead of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> **use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>**.

This way, your copied text will be paste "unformatted", or actually the way your text in mail is.

Answer (score 0):

I share your frustration, Kai. Probably the quickest method is to copy the desired text from your chosen source, then return to your "Write" page in Thunderbird, put the cursor where you want the text to be pasted, then right click and select "Paste without formatting" from the drop-down menu. The copied text will then be pasted in the font and size currently in use in Thunderbird.